# which jquery event to use if I want to perform an action for render of the element every time?

Tags: jquery, events, render

I am trying to use a jquery plugin. I initialized the plugin as per its standard inside the ready() function.
Now, I want to perform some action like showing up a text message every time this plugin object is created by jquery.

Which jQuery event can I use for this?

I am new to jquery and I did not find any event like 'render' in the jquery docs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divId').pluginName({
       //specify elements in the plugin as per its docs
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are callbacks built into some plugins, however it is pretty impossible to help you without knowing more information.  Which plugin are you using and what end result are you trying to achieve?